# Transforming a min() and a max() value into a range of values

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I would like stretch some of my records that were flattened

I have a table like this

```
Store     Min(Date)     Max (Date)     Status
```

---

```
NYC1       1/1/2013      2/1/2013      Open
NYC1       2/2/2013      2/3/2013      Closed for Inspection
Boston1    1/1/2013      2/5/2013      Open
```

and I would like to stretch it into the form

```
Store       Date        Status
```

---

```
 NYC1       1/1/2013     Open
 NYC1       1/2/2013     Open
 .....
 NYC1       2/2/2013     Closed for Inspection
 NYC1       2/3/2013     Closed for Inspection
 ....
 Boston1    1/1/2013     Open
```

I know I can always write loops for this, but before attempting so, I would like to ask if there's any quick and dirty way of doing it?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:datatable] tag. Please verify that you're using the correct tags for your questions to ensure you get the most relevant answers. Can you verify whether you are using an R `data.frame` for your data, or whether you are using the "data.table" package?

Comment: thanks. I was using a data.frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach:

#### Read in your data and convert your dates to actual date variables:

```
mydf <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
text = "Store     Min(Date)     Max(Date)     Status
NYC1       1/1/2013      2/1/2013      Open
NYC1       2/2/2013      2/3/2013      'Closed for Inspection'
Boston1    1/1/2013      2/5/2013      Open")

names(mydf) <- c("store", "min.date", "max.date", "status")
mydf$min.date <- as.Date(mydf$min.date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
mydf$max.date <- as.Date(mydf$max.date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
mydf
#     store   min.date   max.date                status
# 1    NYC1 2013-01-01 2013-02-01                  Open
# 2    NYC1 2013-02-02 2013-02-03 Closed for Inspection
# 3 Boston1 2013-01-01 2013-02-05                  Open
```

#### Calculate the difference in days between "min.date" and "max.date"

Use that information to "expand" your `data.frame` and to generate the date sequence between "min.date" and "max.date". Also, subset the `data.frame` to return just the "store", "date" (our new variable), and "status" variables.

```
SEQ <- mydf$max.date - mydf$min.date + 1
mydf2 <- mydf[rep(row.names(mydf), SEQ), ]
mydf2$date <- mydf2$min.date + sequence(SEQ)-1

mydf2 <- mydf2[c("store", "date", "status")]
```

Here's a sample of the output.

```
head(mydf2)
#     store       date status
# 1    NYC1 2013-01-01   Open
# 1.1  NYC1 2013-01-02   Open
# 1.2  NYC1 2013-01-03   Open
# 1.3  NYC1 2013-01-04   Open
# 1.4  NYC1 2013-01-05   Open
# 1.5  NYC1 2013-01-06   Open
tail(mydf2)
#        store       date status
# 3.30 Boston1 2013-01-31   Open
# 3.31 Boston1 2013-02-01   Open
# 3.32 Boston1 2013-02-02   Open
# 3.33 Boston1 2013-02-03   Open
# 3.34 Boston1 2013-02-04   Open
# 3.35 Boston1 2013-02-05   Open
```

---

You can use `by` to verify we did everything correctly:

```
> with(mydf2, by(date, list(store, status), FUN = range))
: Boston1
: Closed for Inspection
NULL
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
: NYC1
: Closed for Inspection
[1] "2013-02-02" "2013-02-03"
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
: Boston1
: Open
[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-02-05"
----------------------------------------------------------------- 
: NYC1
: Open
[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` for syntax elegance (and assuming the preprocessing by @Ananda

```
mydf <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
text = "Store     Min(Date)     Max(Date)     Status
NYC1       1/1/2013      2/1/2013      Open
NYC1       2/2/2013      2/3/2013      'Closed for Inspection'
Boston1    1/1/2013      2/5/2013      Open")

names(mydf) <- c("store", "min.date", "max.date", "status")
mydf$min.date <- as.Date(mydf$min.date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
mydf$max.date <- as.Date(mydf$max.date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, list(dates = seq(min.date,max.date, by = 1)) , by = list(store,status)]
```

Comment: +1. The `seq` implementation possible with `data.table` *is* definitely slick. I had tried to use `seq` in base, but it involved an ugly `apply` that converted the new "date" variable to numeric, so it had to be re-converted, and in the end, was less efficient than the solution I ended up suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Green Demon

Given your question has the reshape package tag, the easiest thing I can think of is to simply use the melt function. Let's call your data.frame 'foo'. The code below should give you what you want.

```
library(reshape)
foo.melt<-melt(foo, id.vars=c('Store','Status'))
```

Note that this will create an additional column 'variable' with min.date and max.date.

Cheers,

Danny

Comment: Um. No. Did you try this before posting your answer? That basically stacks the `data.frame` but doesn't expand the date sequence, as requested by the OP. Thus, with the three-row example provided by the OP, your result will end up with a six-row `data.frame`, while for this particular problem, they are looking for a 70 row `data.frame`. Pretty big difference! Also, by this point, you should be recommending the "reshape2" package, not "reshape".

Comment: That's what I thought he wanted to do, but now I see what you mean. It wasn't very clear though given the example.